# C output on terminal doesn't have it's own line

Tags: c, terminal

I just started my C programming class today and I am having a problem with the output on my terminal which the C doesn't print on it's own line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(){

    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
```

}

[image]

Comment: You didn't tell the program to finish its output with a newline, so it didn't print one.  What do you expect?  Make sure you terminate lines of output with a newline so that the output appears on its own line.

Comment: `printf("Hello World\n");` will fix the problem.

Comment: Hi, can you please edit your question following to: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) from the Stack Overflow Help Center. Thanks

Comment: @Lundin we don't have books

Comment: printf() doesn't automatically add a newline line like puts() does. You have to add it explicitly if you want it. (This feature can be used to your advantage to output text to a line over a sequence of calls).

Comment: Read at least 2 books before asking anything!

Comment: @AllenTran Tough luck.

Comment: any half decent tutorial then?

Comment: @AllenTran Don't post screenshots (images), just copy and paste the output is fine. Also, this is such a basic problem that any tutorial would have taught you this in the first lesson. SO should not be your go-to resource for answering beginner questions - it should be a last resort after you've tried and failed a reasonable amount of your own effort (hours).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a newline character, represented as `'\n'`. The slash is an escape character for a few special characters, such as tab `'\t'`, and carriage return `'\r'`.

`printf("Hello World\n");`

Comment: printf("%s\n", "Hello World");  Maybe better format

Comment: @G.Noulas why is it better?

Comment: @MichaelWalz This way is prefered (for me) because it can be used for more complex cases in a clearer way and controls the variable types.

Comment: Maybe `puts("Hello World")`?